# Toss a coin until you get НTHT. Expected number of tails tossed?

Tags: probability-theory

You toss a fair coin unlimited
number of times.
How many throws on average do you need to make before the sequence НTHT appears?
The correct answer is the expectation is the sum of the inverse probabilities
of each prefix in a word, which is also a suffix
of the same word. In the case of HTHT, such suffixes-prefixes are
HT and HTHT. But I do not know how to get such an answer :(

Comment: Are you asking for the expected number of tails tossed, or the expected number of throws?  I think the expected number of throws is significantly easier to get.

Comment: I'm asking for the expected number of throws. I know another solution, but it is much faster and I want to understand it

Comment: Is the solution you know the martingale based solution?  Or another one?

Comment: I'm just using the definition of expectation and calculating the sum of number series
For example  E[HT] = 1/2(E[H] + 1) + 1/2(1/2(E[T] + 2) + 1/2(...))
I don't know if this works for any sequence, but for this and some others the answer is correct

Comment: But it takes a very long time to calculate if the sequence is long and you have to analyze many cases

Comment: @Alice The martingale solution: You offer a fair game on coinflips. At each round a new player arrives and they all play an identical strategy: they start betting \$1 and each subsequent round bet all their winnings till they lose, at which point they walk away, having lost \$1. If the sequence is HTHT, they each bet on H first, then T, then H, then T. You end the game once one of them wins all 4 rounds. Your expected earnings must be zero, and from this you can calculate the expected number of rounds (note e.g. if it's HTHT there will be 2 players who get positive payouts)